# How to add two timedate variables?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

```
total = "00:00:00"
# calculating a "lap" , it will never have Y,M,D , but the log contain it.
laptime = str(datetime.strptime(timeend, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") - datetime.strptime(timestart, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

#failing at hiw to add it to "total"
total = datetime.combine(datetime.strptime(total, "%H:%M:%S") + datetime.strptime(laptime, "%H:%M:%S"))
```

I tried combine but no success.
how can I add(accumulate) `laptime` ?

Comment: what's your `timeend` and `timestart` value? Have you tried using `Datetime` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
import datetime as datetime
t1 = datetime.strptime("2018-02-01 14:55:27", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
t2 = datetime.strptime("2018-02-01 14:59:24", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

#for difference
r1 = str(t2 - t1) 
#output 
'0:03:57'

#for adding
r2 = str(t2+ (t2-t1))

#output 
'2018-02-01 15:03:21'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I fail to adapt your example, my indata is more like:
`
t1 = "2018-02-01 14:55:27"
t2 = "2018-02-01 14:59:24"
from datetime import datetime
r1 = str(datetime.strptime(t2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") - datetime.strptime(t1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) 
`
at this point r1 is 0:03:57  , but I have great trouble adding to it , like  r1 + r1 =

Comment: just use for adding t2+(t2-t1) or check answer now